# How inheritance variables from another class?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to inheritance a variables from another class. I write code in C# and I created two classes

First one is Osoba (engl. Person) which has variables ime, prezime, OIB (engl. name, last name, ID) and I have another class Racun (engl. account) which means bank account.

Class Racun has variables podaci o vlasniku računa (engl. account holder information), broj računa (engl. serial number of account) and stanje računa (engl. bank account balance).

Well podaci o vlasniku računa (engl. account holder information) needs to have variables from class Osoba. How can I do that?

I will show you my two created classes with code. If you notice both classes need to have 3 variables, I didn't create first variable in class Racun (engl. account) because the first one need to contain variables from class Osoba (engl. Person).

Osoba.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vjezba6_1
{
    class Osoba
    {
        public string ime { get; set; }
        public string prezime { get; set; }
        public int oib { get; set; }

        public Osoba(string tempIme, string tempPrezime, int tempOib)
        {
            this.ime = tempIme;
            this.prezime = tempPrezime;
            this.oib = tempOib;
        }
    }
}
```

Racun.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vjezba6_1
{
    class Racun
    {
        public int brojRacuna { get; set; }
        public int stanjeRacuna { get; set; }

        public Racun(int tempPovr, int tempbrojRacuna, int tempstanjeRacuna)
        {
            this.povr = tempPovr;
            this.brojRacuna = tempbrojRacuna;
            this.stanjeRacuna = tempstanjeRacuna;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `povr` variable needs to hold the same pieces of information as in `Osoba`, you can either have `povr` be a reference to an instance of `Osoba`:

```
class Racun
{
    public Osoba povr { get; set; }
    public int brojRacuna { get; set; }
    public int stanjeRacuna { get; set; }

    public Racun(Osoba tempPovr, int tempbrojRacuna, int tempstanjeRacuna)
    {
        this.povr = tempPovr;
        //etc
```

Or you could make a `struct` to hold common information:

```
namespace Vjezba6_1
{
    struct PodaciOVlasnikuRacuna //i'm sure you can shorten this, but i don't know the language
    {
         public string ime;
         public string prezime;
         //other account holder information
    }
}
```

And use this in your classes, like so:

```
namespace Vjezba6_1
{
    class Osoba
    {
        public PodaciOVlasnikuRacuna podaci { get; set; }

        public Osoba(string tempIme, string tempPrezime, int tempOib)
        {
            this.podaci.ime = tempIme;
            this.podaci.prezime = tempPrezime;
            this.podaci.oib = tempOib;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You help me a lot, I understand little more now, but problem is when I write a constructor Visual studio marks me as red. "povr" is acctually a short from PodaciOVLasnikuRacuna but I didn't mention that, sorry my mistake. I do struct and than I try to do that in class Osoba and my constructor loock like this.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer helpful. When Visual Studio gives you the red marking, hover your cursor over it and observe the message. If you repeat it here I can try helping you fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Vjezba6_1_v2
{
    class Osoba
    {
        public Podaci povr { get; set; }

        public Osoba(string tempIme, string tempPrezime, int tempOib)
        {
            this.povr.ime = tempIme;
            this.povr.prezime = tempPrezime;
            this.povr.oib = tempOib;
        }
    }
}
```